# Controlling a modalpopup from multiple buttons to show different charts

Tags: c#, .net, modalpopup

I would like to present several buttons on a page that each pop up a different chart.  I used a modalpopup for the first one, and I'm looking for an efficient way to manage the rest.  While I could create separate modalpopups for each chart, that seems very wasteful.  I'm using C#.

Is there a way to have each of these buttons use the same modalpopup but run separate functions in codebehind to bind the chart differently?  Or is there a completely different approach that would work for this?

Thanks.

Edit: Adding Code Sample (scrubbed)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" 
              style="padding-left:12px;" 
              runat="server"
           ImageUrl="images/chart_icon.png" 
            onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" 
        runat="server" 
       Height="350px"  
        Width="700px" 
     CssClass="modalPopup" 
    BackColor="#122b7c" 
  BorderColor="#3366FF" 
  BorderStyle="Solid" 
  BorderWidth="1px" 
      Visible="false">

<div align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" 
            runat="server" 
           Height="300px" 
            Width="690px" 
          Visible="false"
 ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation">

    <Series></Series>
    <ChartAreas></ChartAreas>

    </asp:Chart>

</div>
<div align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnModalCancel" 
             style="margin-top:10px;" 
             runat="server" 
              Text="Close" />
</div>

<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Panel2_ModalPopupExtender" 
                     runat="server"
        DynamicServicePath="" 
                   Enabled="True" 
           TargetControlID="ImageButton1"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
           CancelControlID="btnModalCancel"
                DropShadow="true" 
            PopupControlID="Panel2">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

</asp:Panel>
```

I looked at an answer where two separate buttons (like my ImageButton) were using JavaScript to trigger the onclick event of a hidden button, but I need to do some different code behind for each so I don't know if that works.  If I could trigger the hidden button click event from another button's onclick event in a way that the modalpopupextender recognized it and fired the popup to show I would be good.

Comment: Mh the big problem right now is, that you're using the Ajax Control Toolkit. It's like I can't see through right now because the outcome that's generated by the ACT is horrible. I would have done it with simple jQuery modal. It's first or all easier and more transparent: [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: Thanks, perhaps that will help me get around this.  I'll take a look soon.

Answer (score 0):

**simple approach:**

Think about using different charts in your modal popup that you hide or show based on the popup you're using.

**advanced approach:**

On big projects we use ajax to generate the content that is loaded into modal popups if we're using like images or shapes/charts.

How are you generating the charts?

Comment: I have an MSChart control that I bind at runtime to a LINQ query.  If I use different chart controls, how do I hide/show them in codebehind on the button click?  The OnClick event doesn't seem to trigger when it's used as a modalpopup target.

Comment: That kind of thing is mostly solved with some jQuery. Have you worked with it yet? Could you provide some of the page's code, then I could write an example.

Comment: It's a pretty heavy page but I have done a bit with jquery. I could adapt almost any clean example but I'll try to put something into the question if it helps